# Android widget with changing text

Tags: android, animation, widget

I'm attempting to create an incredibly simple widget that changes the text displayed every 5s or so. However I've had major headaches attempting to get this to work. Obviously I can't use the onUpdate call as it's a minimum of every 30min.
Currently my solution uses an Timer in an extended Service class, which is as ugly as hell and tends to run like a dog after a while. Is there a "clean" way of doing this, ie. in a manner that doesn't require a Widget, UpdateService, Timers etc.

I'm not asking for an entire solution, just a pointer as to how to go about doing this in an efficient manner.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CountdownTimer`:

```
 new CountdownTimer(5000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

What i have done is added the below process that is called in your Widget Provider.... like so...

so the widget will update for the next 24 hours every 30secs....

I have also in my main app code I have a few prefs that I update and then I use the provider event to then call the timer that pulls the pref info.... updating with no service :)

```
 @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

        try {
            final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
                updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);


            }

        updateWidgetView(context, context.getSharedPreferences(
                    MainActivity.APP_PREFERENCES,
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }





    }




 public static void updateAppWidget(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
              final int appWidgetId){

        Context c;
         c = context;
             try {

                 new CountDownTimer(86400, 30000) {

                     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    //do proc every 30sec here. pull prefs and show them                            
                         SharedPreferences preferencesaa = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); 

                          String drinkmsg = preferencesaa.getString("WIDGETTEXT", "You need to drink water.");

                         RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
                         updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text_threat, drinkmsg.toString());

                         appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews); 
                     }

                     public void onFinish() {

                     }
                  }.start();



            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
```

[First App that I am about to release.  8 Cups a Day™](http://8cupsaday.com)